# How is LSD an incomplete three-way layout?

Tags: experiment-design, latin-square

How is the Latin square design(LSD) an incomplete three-way layout? In this context, let me ask also what is a complete layout?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Latin square with the row index as the level of factor X, the column index as the level of factor Y, and the symbol as the level of factor Z.  I've not heard Latin squares described this way, but one might call such a design incomplete in the sense that not every combination of factor levels occurs in some run.  That is, it's a proper subset of the factorial design.

Consider the following example: a $4 \times 4$ Latin square

```
ABDC
BCAD
CDBA
DACB
```

can be transformed into the following design

```
A   1   1
A   2   3
A   3   4
A   4   2
B   1   2
B   2   1
B   3   3
B   4   4
C   1   4
C   2   2
C   3   1
C   4   3
D   1   3
D   2   4
D   3   2
D   4   1
```

This design is also an orthogonal array of strength 2.